# Total DataTable column where ID duplicate

Tags: vb.net, full-text-search

I am searching a table in MSSQL using full-text-search. This table contains the summary and content for support incidents. the summary is identified by having an EVENT_TYPE of Open.

I want to search all event types so I've set-up full-text-search on the field containing the relevant text (COMMENTS). Now I only want to display the summary row on the screen (DataGridView) as the other updates are accessed once the summary row has been selected.

I only want rows with an EVENT_TYPE of 'Open' shown, so I'm using:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = " [EVENT_TYPE] = 'Open'"
```

I have a column called Match which gives the percentage match for each result, how would I combine the results for all rows with the same ID?

i.e Add up all of the match scores for all rows that have a duplicate ID number, adding to a new column?

```
ID | EVENT_TYPE| match
123     Open       33
123     Closed     47
123     Update     12
```

Would ideally be displayed as:

```
ID | EVENT_TYPE| match | matchTotal
123     Open       33        92
```

I thought it might be a case of using datatables Compute but it doesn't appear to be that easy, I don't think it's possible to filter in the way required.

```
dt.Compute("Sum(Match)", "[EVENT_TYPE] = 'Open' AND Duplicate(INCIDENT_ID)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try LINQ:

```
Dim q = From p In dt
Group p By tID = p(0) _
Into matchTotal= Sum(Convert.ToDouble(p(2))) _
Select tID, totalForType
'Where dt is your original datatable
```

I know that this will have as result this:

```
 ID |  matchTotal
 123       92
```

But I am providing you a start point.